# Improve protection of device that got damaged by a primary side short

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, mains, protection, industrial

Today I swapped one of our devices that got damaged by the customer during installation. The device consists of a base board with several modules (power supply, IO cards, processor board, display+USB, ...).

The device was specced with 230V AC supply that basically consists of a daughterboard with two off-the-shelf potted SMPS modules, two fuses and a board-to-board connector for the secondary side. Primary side is connected on the power supply module. The customer seems to have removed the PS module while it was still connected to mains and appears to have shorted the solder connections of the input to the chassis of our device via one of the standoffs that the PS module is mounted with.

This blew the primary fuse and blew several inches of PE copper track off the base board. The device was earthed via the PCB mounting screws to the aluminum case and from there to the machine it was mounted to.
After replacing the fuse (and later attempting to bridge the blown PE track), the device came back on (processor was running, customer could configure it via the display/buttons), however the device did not switch any of it's relays, nor was the customer able to connect it to his laptop via the onboard FTDI + USB jack.

The relay issue is related to the relay driver IC (PCF8574), which sits directly below the power supply module and had a burnt pin. The USB issue is probably because the CPU (STM32F407) and/or the FT232RL were damaged as well. I will test this tomorrow.

What would be best practice protection circuitry in order to avoid damaging the device in a case like this?

There's a primary side fuse as mentioned, two secondary fuses (one per SMPS) and some local 5V and 3.3V regulation going on right now. Since there are also DC power supply options, there is a reverse protection diode on those supply modules, before the dc-dc module (also off-the-shelf on custom daughterboard).

Would MOVs/diode clamping/TVS diodes improve the situation? Would I add those to the base board or to each daughterboard that has it's own regulation? What about polyfuses? Other suggestions?

The device is used in rough industrial environments, protected by a die-cast aluminum case (with crimped-on earth connection for the case and the lid).

Comment: Do you know which path the current took? Did a high voltage line get shorted to a low voltage line? Why was the relay driver burnt?

Comment: Sounds like the best solution is mechanical : at the very least there should be no way exposed mains wiring on a moveable module can short to any metalwork. Insulating "rubber boots" or plastic covers : these can easily and cheaply be custom made. Also consider re-designing such that you cannot remove the module with mains power connected (e.g. socket is on fixed metalwork; locking screws cannot be accessed without unplugging, etc.

Comment: _"The **customer** seems to have removed the PS module while it was still connected to mains... What would be best practice protection circuitry in order to avoid damaging the device in a case like this?" - a switch or mechanical interlock to prevent opening the case with the power on, and a strongly worded disclaimer in the warranty!